# UDP Multicast packets received by TShark but not C/C++ app

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, multicast

Summary:

TShark shows multicast packets being received on a particular interface but when I connect to that interface's inet/local IP address, with the multicast address and port, I don't receive them.

Running `tshark <interface_name>` shows multicast data being received:

```
230159 27.010051471 206.1.2.3 -> 233.1.2.3 UDP 121 Source port: 5000 Destination port: 6000
```

`ifconfig` shows the inet address for `interface_name` is:

```
inet 172.1.2.3
```

I set the multicast address, port and local interface address but the code just blocks on `recvfrom()`.

I have looked at three different examples online, tried them all and I get the same problem.

From the Linux side our interface is bonded (not an expert on this, just know it's a bonded interface). Does this require the C/C++ to be configured differently??

The code:

```
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) 
    {
        LOG("Error opening datagram socket");
    }

    int reuse=1;
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0) 
    {
        close(sock);
        LOG("Error setting SO_REUSEADDR");
    }

    struct sockaddr_in localSock;
    memset((char *) &localSock, 0, sizeof(localSock));
    localSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    localSock.sin_port = htons(6000);
    localSock.sin_addr.s_addr  = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&localSock, sizeof(localSock))) 
    {
        close(sock);
        LOG("Error binding datagram socket");
    }

    struct ip_mreq group;
    group.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr("233.1.2.3");  // Multicast group address
    group.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr("172.1.2.3");  // interface local IP

    if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char *)&group, sizeof(group)) < 0) 
    {
        close(sock);
        LOG("Error adding multicast group");
    }

    LOG("Listening... ");

    while (1) 
    {
        socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(localSock);

        // The -1 is because a '\0' will be written at the end too
        const size_t maxNumBytesToRead = MSGBUFSIZE - 1;
        const int nbytes = recvfrom(sock, msgbuf, maxNumBytesToRead, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &localSock, &addrlen);
        assert(nbytes > 0);

        const HEADER header = *reinterpret_cast<const HEADER*>(&msgbuf[0]);
        const uint64_t seqNum = header.getSeqNum();

        LOG("Received seqNum: " << seqNum);
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202927/discussion-on-question-by-user997112-udp-multicast-packets-received-by-tshark-bu).